# Using Microsoft Query and SQL Procedure to return data in multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL that I am calling from Excel.  I'm passing a single parameter and a value is returned.  When I set this up in Microsoft Query, I type in my query using the SQL dialog, set up the parameter to pull from (for example) cell B4 and return the data to D4.  From a SQL, passing parameters, return, etc. perspective, this works great.  What's incorrect is the way the return values are placed in the sheet, and how I get it to work for all of the rows.  So what I get back looks like this:

[Image of what I'm getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1SKc.png)

What I really want is for the 11.45  to be returned in D4 (which is what I specified in Microsoft Query), without the header in C4.  Further, I need to 'copy' this from D2 to D40, as I'd like to process the same procedure against all of the data in column B.  What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MS Query is not designed to be run for each row in excel. You would have as many queries as lines in excel and would spam the server with multiple queries.

Your procedure could accept a lower and upper date and return data to a new sheet, and the current sheet can link to it, or you could generate the whole sheet from the stored procedure.

In any case, i can't see how calling a SP for each row is going to work.

Comment: Ok, then maybe I should take a step back and ask how this problem should be solved?  I have a column of data in excel that needs to be passed to SQL server and a procedure run against each of the values in the column, returning the single result per input value in a corresponding cell.

Comment: it depends on your situation. I would say that you *could* concatenate all rows in column B and send them to the stored procedure as one large variable. Then you do the reverse and populate column D from the result. But ideally, if you can upload the file to the server, you could load the whole sheet in SQL using Ace OLEdb, parse the sheet and create a new excel file. There's also the option of using OpenXML to parse the file but that is a long and tedious process imho...